# Firestore interface collapse fields by default (console.firebase.google)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Google Firestore for a project and the "Cloud Firestore" interface for dealing with the database expands all document fields by default. This makes it tough to alter the data as I have a few large arrays in my sample data that cause me to have to collapse many fields before reaching the desired field.

**Is there a way to set the data/fields to be collapsed by default?** This is mainly a quality of life thing while I'm in MVP mode. For reference I've checked the documentation, reddit and stack overflow for an answer but haven't found a solution. I've also submitted this as a feature request just in case.

Edit for comment:
To clarify, I am referring to the console.firebase.google UI for Firestore. See the attached image (random image from google) for reference.

[image]

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "collapsed by default".  Please edit the question to go into more detail that includes the code that isn't working the way you expect, and how you observe that the result is something other than what you expect.

Comment: @DougStevenson - I'm actually not referring to code. I'm referring to the console.firebase.google UI for editing Firestore JSON. While I'm MVP'ing it's convenient to just do minor or individual edits online. I've included a screenshot that I hope clarifies what I mean by collapsible fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to change the behavior of the console in the way you're suggesting.  The way in which you add the data makes no difference.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just wanted to make sure, just in case I was missing something somewhere. I've submitted it as a requested feature, but it's more just a "would be nice to have" sorta thing so that's ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can use not "Firebase Console" but "Google Cloud Console" (or what it calls):
https://console.cloud.google.com/firestore/databases/-default-/data/panel

It looks the same, but all fields collapsed by default.